# Achieve forms in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can we achieve UI like below screenshot in react native, rather forms ? 
Are those possible ?

[image]

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: Are you looking for a npm package to use immediately? Or are you asking how to make the UI like your screenshot?

Comment: Im asking what could be the best solution to achieve UI like this , and is it possible with forms @Daniel shared link. 

AS the screenshot suggest + and - buttons are to add the repetitive UI.

Comment: KarI ->  haven't gave it a shot yet, but tried with tcomb library, which @Daniel shared. Im new to react-native so getting the suggestions from community about the best way.

Comment: @Rajesh, can you show us what you have tried thus far, are you using react-redux? Can you confirm if the answer provided was the correct one? If so, can you please check it off so others may benefit?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to build forms in react native you may use [tcomb-form-native](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native). It provides an easy interface to quickly build a form.

EDIT:

To build the exact same UI, you would have to restrict the widths of the elements using [Flexbox](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.24/docs/flexbox.html#flexbox).

Comment: I have tried this already for different form, but can we achieve the the screenshot UI using this library ? can we manage the width of text inputs ?